# Not Getting Dynamic URL of a Popup opening in a new tab in Testcafe

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When a button is clicked, a new tab opens which has a dynamic URL, we need to close that tab after a verification and get back to the main tab.
Is it possible to navigate to a new tab having a dynamic URL in Testcafe? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getCurrentWindow](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402699/reference/test-api/testcontroller/getcurrentwindow) method to get the descriptor of the current window. This means that you can call this method in the initial and the new window.
After you have all windows descriptors you can switch between windows using the [switchToWindow](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402677/reference/test-api/testcontroller/switchtowindow) method.

If these methods do not suit you, please share your example to demonstrate the issue in detail.

Comment: Thank you for Answering, but this approach did not work as expected, the issue is explained in detail in the next comment.

Comment: "blob:https://myproject.com/57019f99-239e-426a-8cb2-fee08b67e519" -> This is a sample Url generated after clicking the print button. Here the part "blob:https://myproject.com/" is static and this value -> "57019f99-239e-426a-8cb2-fee08b67e519", keeps changing all the time, we want to close the new window opened which has this dynamic URL as the testcafe script does not move ahead due to this new window, please suggest a way by which we close this new window and our script can proceed further steps in the automation process, let us know if more details are needed.

Comment: Please, share a small example so we can analyze the issue in detail. Or, better yet, submit a new issue at [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) and share as much detail as possible.